# JavaFX, and FXML: Centering a Text in HBox

Tags: javafx, fxml, netbeans-8

I need some help. How do you center a text in HBox. I am using SceneBuilder. I try and I can't figure it out how to do it.

Here is the code for FXML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Point3D?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<top>
  <HBox prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <Text boundsType="LOGICAL_VERTICAL_CENTER" layoutX="600.0" layoutY="600.0" scaleZ="0.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="GIANTS  DATABASE" textAlignment="CENTER" textOrigin="CENTER" wrappingWidth="231.7841796875" x="600.0" y="600.0">
           <rotationAxis>
              <Point3D x="1.0" y="1.0" z="1.0" />
           </rotationAxis>
        </Text>
     </children></HBox>
</top>
<right>
  <TableView prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="577.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <columns>
      <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="72.0" text="Rank" />
      <TableColumn editable="false" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="206.0" text="Name" />
        <TableColumn editable="false" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="88.0" text="Position" />
        <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="School" />
        <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="66.0" text="Age" />
        <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="66.0" text="War" />
    </columns>
  </TableView>
</right>
<opaqueInsets>
  <Insets />
</opaqueInsets>
<padding>
  <Insets bottom="3.0" right="3.0" />
</padding>
```

The text I want to center is **GIANTS DATABASE**, under HBox children

Here is the code for javaFX

```
public class Login extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    try {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/giants/LoginF.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Giants Database Login");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();  
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

**Here is the image of the text *GIANTS DATABASE**. And I want to center the text where the arrow is pointing**

[image: Here is the image. And where the arrow is, that is where I want to center]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `bounds`, `layoutX/Y` and `rotation` settings on the `Text` node - they are not needed for this.  What you are looking for is the `HBox` [`alignment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#alignmentProperty) property - setting it to `Pos.CENTER` will layout the children of the `HBox` in the center both vertically and horizontally. If you want to keep it to the left use `Pos.CENTER_LEFT`.

It is also not clear from your question whether you wish for the HBox to be this tall - it may be helpful to change the `prefHeight` of the `HBox` to `Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` to have it match the size of the `Text` note (plus any padding/margins set on either of them).